# Aggregate nodes based on conditon under new parent

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an given XML and I want to convert it in new xml and want to aggregate nodes based on status and orderId.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrderStatusUpdate>
    <OrderStatusEvents>
        <OrderStatusEvent>
          <StoreCode>store1</StoreCode>
          <OrderId>Order1</OrderId>
          <ItemId>Item1</ItemId>
          <OrderStatusDetails>
            <OrderStatusDetail>
              <OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>2017-03-19 03:37:05</OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>
              <StatusName>Cancelled</StatusName>
            </OrderStatusDetail>
          </OrderStatusDetails>
        </OrderStatusEvent>
        <OrderStatusEvent>
          <StoreCode>Store1</StoreCode>
          <OrderId>Order1</OrderId>
          <ItemId>Item2</ItemId>
          <OrderStatusDetails>
            <OrderStatusDetail>
              <OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>2017-03-19 03:48:35</OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>
              <StatusName>Cancelled</StatusName>
            </OrderStatusDetail>
          </OrderStatusDetails>
        </OrderStatusEvent>
        <OrderStatusEvent>
          <StoreCode>Store1</StoreCode>
          <OrderId>Order1</OrderId>
          <ItemId>Item3</ItemId>
          <OrderStatusDetails>
            <OrderStatusDetail>
              <OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>2017-03-19 03:48:35</OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>
              <StatusName>Shipped</StatusName>
            </OrderStatusDetail>
          </OrderStatusDetails>
        </OrderStatusEvent>
        <OrderStatusEvent>
      <StoreCode>Store1</StoreCode>
      <OrderId>Order2</OrderId>
      <ItemId>Item1</ItemId>
      <OrderStatusDetails>
        <OrderStatusDetail>
          <OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>2017-03-19 03:48:35</OrderStatusEventTimeStamp>
          <StatusName>Cancelled</StatusName>
        </OrderStatusDetail>
      </OrderStatusDetails>
    </OrderStatusEvent>
    </OrderStatusEvents>
</OrderStatusUpdate>
```

And I want an output like this. Here I am grouping elements based on status and orderId.

```
     <Orders>
    <group name="CANCELLED">
        <STATUS ID="CANCELLED" DESCRIPTION="Goods Cancelled">
                <ORDER ID="Order1">
                    <ORDER_ITEM item="item1" />
                    <ORDER_ITEM item="item2" />
                </ORDER>
        </STATUS>
        <STATUS ID="CANCELLED" DESCRIPTION="Goods Cancelled">
                <ORDER ID="Order2">
                    <ORDER_ITEM item="item1" />
                </ORDER>
        </STATUS>
    </group>
    <group name="SHIPPED">
        <STATUS ID="SHIPPED" DESCRIPTION="Goods SHIPPED">
                <ORDER ID="Order1">
                    <ORDER_ITEM item="item3" />
                </ORDER>
        </STATUS>
    <group>
</Orders>
```

I am using the following xslt and it is working fine. Is there any way to improve this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="OrderStatusUpdate/OrderStatusEvents">
        <Orders>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="OrderStatusEvent" group-by="OrderStatusDetails/OrderStatusDetail/StatusName">
                <xsl:variable name="group-name" select="current-grouping-key()" />
                <group name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="OrderId">
                        <xsl:variable name="order-id" select="current-grouping-key()" />
                         <xsl:element name="STATUS">
                            <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="$group-name" /></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="DESCRIPTION">Goods <xsl:value-of select="$group-name" /></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:element name="ORDER">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="$order-id" /></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                        <xsl:if test="$group-name = 'Shipped'">
                                            <xsl:call-template name="Shipped">
                                                <xsl:with-param name="nodes">
                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                                                </xsl:with-param>
                                            </xsl:call-template>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="$group-name = 'Cancelled'">
                                            <xsl:call-template name="Cancelled">
                                                <xsl:with-param name="nodes">
                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                                                </xsl:with-param>
                                            </xsl:call-template>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Orders>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Shipped">
        <xsl:param name="nodes">
        </xsl:param>
        <xsl:element name="ORDER_ITEM">
            <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="$nodes/OrderStatusEvent/ItemId" /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Cancelled">
        <xsl:param name="nodes"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:element name="ORDER_ITEM">
            <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="$nodes/OrderStatusEvent/ItemId" /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well,you know what do do as you say "Here I am grouping elements based on status and orderId" so simply use `xsl:for-each-group` as exemplified in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples.

Comment: I am able to group but unable to add parent <ORDER ID="Order1"> element. I am trying for-each-group for status then under this I am using another for-each-group for orderId but unable to create a parent element for similar orderId items

Comment: Please edit your question showing the current XSLT with nested `xsl:for-each-group` you have, together with the output it creates, then I am sure we can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use literal result elements and attribute value templates as long as you don't need to compute element or attribute names at run-time and I don't think you need the two templates and call-template, it suffices to use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="OrderStatusUpdate/OrderStatusEvents">
        <Orders>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="OrderStatusEvent" group-by="OrderStatusDetails/OrderStatusDetail/StatusName">
                <xsl:variable name="group-name" select="current-grouping-key()" />
                <group name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="OrderId">
                        <xsl:variable name="order-id" select="current-grouping-key()" />
                        <STATUS ID="{$group-name}" DESCRIPTION="Goods {$group-name}">
                            <ORDER ID="{$order-id}">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                            </ORDER>
                        </STATUS>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Orders>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderStatusEvent">
        <ORDER_ITEM ID="{ItemId}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I need different rendering based on group that's why I put if condition and called different template. Can I do it in easy/shorter way?

Comment: I can only answer that if you actually show a different rendering, as far as I can see the two templates output the same, so please edit the question and show us in what way you need a different output and how you achieve that currently.